# gevent to Tornado ioloop - Structure code with coroutines/generators

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, gevent

I'm trying to convert some fairly straightforward gevent code to use the async facilities of Tornado. The sample code below uses the ZMQ library to do a very simple request-response.

```
import zmq.green as zmq

def fun():
    i = zmq.Context.instance()
    sock = i.socket(zmq.REQ)
    sock.connect('tcp://localhost:9005')
    sock.send('Ping')
    return sock.recv()
```

I can run this as `fun()` anywhere in my code. The `.recv()` call blocks while waiting for a reply, and the `gevent` hub can schedule the other parts of the code. When values are received, the function returns the value.

I read the [problems that can arise with these implicit returns](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html), and I want to run this using the Tornado IOLoop (also because I want to run it within the IPython Notebook). The following is an option, where `recv_future()` returns a `Future` that contains the result:

```
@gen.coroutine
def fun():
    i = zmq.Context.instance()
    sock = i.socket(zmq.REQ)
    sock.connect('tcp://localhost:9005')
    sock.send('Ping')
    msg = yield recv_future(sock)
    print "Received {}".format(msg[0])
    raise gen.Return(msg)

def recv_future(socket):
    zmqstream = ZMQStream(socket)  # Required for ZMQ
    future = Future()
    def _finish(reply):
        future.set_result(reply)
    zmqstream.on_recv(_finish)
    return future
```

The problem is that now `fun()` is not a function, but is a generator. So if I need to call it from another function, I need to use `yield fun()`. But then the calling function also becomes a generator!

What is the right way to structure code that uses Python generators? Do I have to make every function a generator to make it work? What if I need to call one of these functions from `__init__()`? Should that also become a generator?

Answer (score 1):

> What if I need to call one of these functions from `__init__()`? Should
>   that also become a generator?

This is one of the currently unsolved issues with explicit asynchronous programming with `yield` /`yield from` (on Python 3.3+). Magic methods don't support them. You can read some interesting thoughts from a Python core developer on asynchronous programming that touches on this issue [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/pep_ideas/async_programming.html).

> What is the right way to structure code that uses Python generators?
>   Do I have to make every function a generator to make it work?
>   Not *every* function, but every function that you want to call a coroutine, and wait for that coroutine to finish before continuing. When you switch to an explicit asynchronous programming model, you generally want to go all-in with it - your entire program runs inside the tornado ioloop. So, with this toy example, you would just do:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.concurrent import Future

@gen.coroutine
def fun():
    i = zmq.Context.instance()
    sock = i.socket(zmq.REQ)
    sock.connect('tcp://localhost:9005')
    sock.send('Ping')
    msg = yield recv_future(sock)
    print "Received {}".format(msg[0])
    raise gen.Return(msg)

def recv_future(socket):
    zmqstream = ZMQStream(socket)  # Required for ZMQ
    future = Future()
    def _finish(reply):
        future.set_result(reply)
    zmqstream.on_recv(_finish)
    return future

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.add_callback(fun)
    ioloop.start() # This will run fun, and then block forever.
    #ioloop.run_sync(fun) # This will start the ioloop, run fun, then stop the ioloop
```

It looks like you might be able to get access to the ioloop IPython is using via the [IPython.kernel API](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.kernel.ioloop.manager.html):

```
In [4]: from IPython.kernel.ioloop import manager

In [5]: manager.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
Out[5]: <zmq.eventloop.ioloop.ZMQIOLoop at 0x4249ac8>
```